# How to insert into multiple tables from one table through procedures?

Tags: oracle11g, procedures

There are 4 tables

```
Table1(Column11, Column12, Column13)
Table2(Column21, Column22)
Table3(Column31, Column32,column33)
Table4(Column21, Column22)
```

And the following Mapping Table:

```
Table5(Sourcetable,Source column ,Destination table ,Destination column)
```

How to insert data from Table1 as source table and destination table as Table2,table3,table,4, Through Procedures?

I am using oracle 11g. Please help to achieve this!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly do you want? A procedure that reads out the source table/column and destination table/column from table5 and then executes the copy?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this is what you are looking for:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cpy_table
AS
CURSOR targ_dest_relation IS
    SELECT sourcetable, sourcecolumn, destinationtable, destinationcolumn FROM table5;

BEGIN
    FOR rec IN targ_dest_relation loop
        execute immediate 'insert into ' || rec.destinationtable || '(' || rec.destinationcolumn || ') select ' || rec.sourcecolumn || ' from ' || rec.sourcetable;
    END loop;
END;
/
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b878d1/1)

Comment: this cursor is helpful but :

Comment: I think you are missing some text. But what?